# Tutorial on functional XML pull processing

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stax

I am looking for a good tutorial on XML pull processing (e.g. StAX) using a functional approach -- no mutable values.

I am imagining that it will involve lots of recursive procedures that process interesting elements and bypass uninteresting ones.

Scala code would be preferable, but I can probably make my way through algorithms in any of the functional languages.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scales Xml Pull Parsing](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.4/RepeatedSections.html) provides a simple abstraction over pull parsing (via stax and Scalaz Iteratees).  Version 0.5 also adds asynchronous pull parsing to the mix.

There is plenty of code in the above mix but it would be great if you could say what kind of xml structure you are processing, it may help make other suggestions.

Comment: The XML is a representation of a JTree containing thousands of nodes (each displaying either a checkbox or radiobuttons). I need to process each node to retrieve some attributes and then recursively process the children.

Comment: I will look at the package you suggested. I may use the library directly or, by examining the source code, the algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that the tree is then not a predefined depth for the leaf nodes containing the checkbox or radiobuttons.
I'd appreciate it if you could post a little snippet.  I'm not so sure from the above that the current high level functions are exactly what you are looking for.  
But it may be that this is a cool new use-case for me :)